# Can I retrieve Salesforce data out of SF using the REST API?

Tags: api, rest, salesforce

I'm having a bad time figuring out if I can retreive an authenticated user's data using the REST API. 
I have managed to authenticate using OAuth 2.0, retrieve all the SObjects ( and each object instances description) using the REST API, but can't figure out how can I can I retrieve the ***actual data*** for each object instances.

I have read the article on "which API should I use?" but it's just not clear enough.

Does any of this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/) Query REST endpoint /services/data/{version}/query?q={soqlQuery}, e.g. with curl

```
curl -v https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT+ID,NAME+FROM+ACCOUNT -H "Authorization: Bearer $SID"
```

If you've already got the SObject definitions then you can use the object/field info to programmatically build the queries (there's no select *, so you need to include every field you want)

Comment: Ok thanks. If I want to get only the updated records per objects (say between certain dates) is there a way to do so in the REST API? I know there is getUpdated method in the SOAP API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm). Is there a similar method in REST? thanks again

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm

Comment: @superfell I am trying to get/update salesforce records using postman... Using the same url that you provided.. please let me know where I need to provide login details for any org ?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use

URI something like     /vXX.X/sobjects/SObjectName/updated/?start=startDateAndTime&end=endDateAndTime

SObjectName can be Account, Opportunity,OpportunityLineItem